# $\limsup_{t \to 0} {L_t}/\sqrt{t} = \infty$ with probability one?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, brownian-motion

Let $B_t$ be a standard Brownian motion, $L(x, t)$ be the local time $x$ at time $t$, and $L_t = L(0, t)$. Do we have$$\limsup_{t \to 0} {{L_t} \over{\sqrt{t}}} = \infty$$with probability one?

Comment: Are you familiar with Levy's theorem which says that local time at 0 has the same distribution as the maximum process $M(t)$?

Comment: @AlexR., why don't you want to write (an extended version of) this comment as an answer?

Comment: It is not that hard to prove this using the hint given by Alex R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to understand why don't you use Alex R.'s hint, so let me write it down.

By Levy's theorem, $L_t$ has the same distribution as $M_t = \sup_{s\in[0,t]} B_t$. So by the law of the iterated logarithm, 
$$
\limsup_{t\to 0+} \frac{L_t}{\sqrt{2t\log \log \frac1t}} = \limsup_{t\to 0+} \frac{M_t}{\sqrt{2t\log \log \frac1t}}\ge  \limsup_{t\to 0+} \frac{B_t}{\sqrt{2t\log \log \frac1t}} = 1.
$$
It follows that the answer to your question is positive.